# Two Calculus Problems- Limit and finding an image of a function

Tags: calculus

Will you please help me solve the following?

1. $\lim _{x\to 0} \dfrac{x-\arctan x}{x-\sin x} $
2. What is the image of the function $ f(x) = \frac{1}{\exp( \sqrt{\cos(\pi \cdot x)-\sin(\pi \cdot x) } )} $ ?

Is there any other way to solve question 1 other than l'Hospital rule ? (I can't think of any)

As for 2 - I tried taking $c\in \operatorname{Im}(f) $ which implies $ \frac{1}{c} = \exp( \sqrt{\cos(\pi \cdot x)-\sin(\pi \cdot x) } ) $  which implies that $\frac{1}{c}$ is in the image of $\exp( \sqrt{\cos(\pi \cdot x)-\sin(\pi \cdot x) } )$  which I can't find...

Will you please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you allowed to use Maclaurin series for 1 ?

Comment: Nope. We still haven't learn it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, L'Hopital looks like the way to go. For 2, all you need is the maximum of $\cos \pi x - \sin \pi x$ (since you are taking square roots, you can't take them for negative argument, so don't have to worry about the minimum).

Comment: As for 1- thanks. That's what I thought. 
As for 2 - the maximum value can be obtained by differentiating and looking for maximum values of this ... Is it the only way ? can't we do it in another way ? Thanks!

Comment: For 2, nothing much simpler comes to mind, though I assume the max (of sin plus cos) is $\sqrt{2}.$